# Area under the curve using idl

Tags: idl-programming-language

I have a curve between dff(x axis) and dc(y axis) and I calculated the area under the curve using IN_TABULATED function.

```
X=[-0.00205553,-0.00186668,-0.00167783,-0.00148899,-0.00130014,-0.00111129,-0.000922443,-0.000733597,-0.000450326,-0.000261480,0.000116216,0.000399487,  0.000588333,0.000777179,0.000966027,0.00115488,0.00134372,0.00153257,0.00172141,0.00181584,0.00200468]
F=[0.00000,21.0000,26.0000,57.0000,94.0000,148.000,248.000,270.000,388.000,418.000,379.000,404.000,358.000,257.000,183.000,132.000,81.0000,47.0000,23.0000,17.0000,431.000]
A=INT_TABULATED(X,F)
print, A
```

Now, I need to have a loop start from n,0 (from right to left) and calculate A1 which is 0.01 of A and to stop there, then print dff values which represent A1's area. How can I do this? Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, so let me begin by stating my interpretation.  You have a curve which integrates to A.  Starting from the right, you want the X-value (let's call it `X1`) which encloses 0.01 of A (the total area under the curve).  In other words, 0.99 of the total area under the curve `F` is to the left of `X1`, and 0.01 of the area is to the right.

Assuming this interpretation is correct, here's a solution:
First, loop through the data and calculate the integral from 0 to each point.

```
npoints = n_elements(x)

; Initialize a vector to hold integration results 
area_cumulative = [] 

; Loop through each data point, calculating integrals from 0 to that point
for index = 0, npoints-1 do begin

    ; Assume area under first point is zero, otherwise, calculate integral
    if index eq 0 then area_up_to_point = 0d0 $
      else area_up_to_point = int_tabulated(x[0:index], f[0:index])

    ; Store integral value in the cumulative vector
        area_cumulative = [area_cumulative, area_up_to_point]

endfor
```

Then, you can interpolate to find `X1`:

```
;;; Find where cumulative distribution reaches 0.99 of A

a1 = 0.99 * a

x1 = interpol(x, area_cumulative, a1)
```

Here's an illustration.  The upper plot is your data, and the lower plot is the cumulative area (integral from x[0] to x).  The red dashed lines show `X1 = 0.001952`.  The gray shaded region contains 0.01 of the total area.

[image: Plot illustrating how to find X1]

Hope this helps!